# A few instances rendered on a page Ruby on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I want to render a few instances of Post object on a single page.

Currently I have in my controller the code:

```
@post = Post.find(1)
```

and in the index view I have:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => Post.find(1) %>
```

Now I want to print the second instance, how to do it? This code for the second instance does not work.

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => Post.find(2) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- When you set instance variable (prefixed with `@`) in your controller, they're available in your views. So you could do something like:

```rb
<%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @post %>
```

- Generally, `index` actions are meant to deal with a collection (`@posts`). I'd expect something like:

```rb
@posts = Post.where(author: current_user)
```

- If you want to display a post identified by an id, I'd recommend taking a look at CRUD operations: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web

Roughly, what you may want to do is something like:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
resources :posts

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'posts/post', locals: { post: @post } %>
```

Remember that controllers sets the instance variables, and views use them

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to show a few instances of post on index page in a slideshow, which would be let's say by id post no. 1, 3, 4? It does not have to be in a slideshow.

Comment: What you don't want is to hard-code IDs. So maybe you'll need an attribute to distinguish these posts. It may not be the best option for you, but you can use a boolean attribute (`highlighted`, for example),  and call `Post.highlighted` to fetch them

Comment: I try to do this by creating variables @a = Post.find(1), @b = Post.find(2), @c = Post.find(3) and putting lines in the view: <%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @a %>, <%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @b %>, <%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @c %>. I get object a printed for three instances...

Comment: When I get Post.highlighted I still want to print a few specific instances in separate places of the page, which means I want to put three times this code. <%= render :partial => 'posts/post', :object => @post %>. Where do I write the instances? or do I have to do Post.highlightedA, Post.highlightedB, Post.highlightedC?

Comment: I created three instances of Post.slideshowa, Post.slideshowb, Post.slideshowc and assigned them to variables @slideshowa = Post.slideshowa, @slideshowb = Post.slideshowb, @slideshowc = Post.slideshowc. I get an error: undefined method `slideshowa' for Post:Class.

Comment: This may be useful: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections

Comment: I think it is not a collection, I want to render them as separate posts. Could you guide me a bit more? I think we are almost there with boolean solution, it's only that it gives this error:  I get an error: undefined method `slideshowa' for Post:Class.